# Spring Boot with kafka with KIP-500 Kraft mode

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kraft

Is the spring boot application supports kafka without zookeeper.

I am able to setup kafka in kraft mode without zookeeper. Now I need to know what I have to set up in the spring boot application to connect with kafka in kraft mode.

I have googled it, to run spring boot application with kafka in kraft mode without zookeeper, but I am not able to find any examples.

Can you one know how to integrate the kafka in kraft mode with spring boot application

Answer (score 0):

Kafka clients don't need to know what mode Kafka is running in.

You configure bootstrap servers as normal.